# Java MockedStatic method is still called

Tags: java, junit, mockito

So I'm using `MockedStatic<>` to mock a static method but it seems like the item inside is still getting called? If this is the case, what's the point of mocking it? I have the following setup:

Object being tested:

```
public class ObjectBeingTested {
  public void methodBeingTested() {
    Object obj = ObjectInQuestion.getInstance(new Object(), "abc");
    // do stuff with obj
  }
}
```

The object with static method:

```
public class ObjectInQuestion {
  public static ObjectInQuestion getInstance(Object obj, String blah) {
     someLocalVar = new FileRequiredObject();
     // we get NullPointerException here cuz in test env, no files found
  }
  
  private ObjectInQuestion() {
    // private constructor to make people use getInstance
  }
  
}
```

Test code:

```
public class MyTestClass {

  MockedStatic<SomeClass> mySomeClass;

  @Mock ObjectInQuestion mMockedObjectInQuestion;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mySomeClass = mockStatic(SomeClass.class);
    when(SomeClass.getInstance(any(), anyString()).thenReturn(mMockedObjectInQuestion);
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    mySomeClass.close();
  }

}
```

My questions are the following:

1. Why calling `ObjectInQuestion.getInstance()` in the test class, it's totally fine but when it's being called from `ObjectBeingTested`, it runs the real construction?
2. I tried to use `mockConstruction` on `FileRequiredObject`, it still actually construct the object ... why?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong syntax for stubbing the static method.  You want something like

```
mySomeClass.when(
    ()->SomeClass.getInstance(any(), anyString()))
    .thenReturn(mMockedObjectInQuestion);
```

More information [available here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods)

Comment: Tried doing that but same result. It still runs the original method `getInstance()` :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MockedStatic<SomeClass> mySomeClass;` is actually `MockedStatic<ObjectInQuestion> mySomeClass;`, I would try to simplify the setup using a classic `try` block.

In any case, sharing the actual test method might be able to shine some light. ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).